# voice recorder with recorder js

Tags: javascript, html, voice-recording

I want make a field to record voice (username,password and a pist of voice) 
i tried to use recorder js in this repo :
https://github.com/cwilso/AudioRecorder

but the problem is when i download this project and try to open it localy it show this error in the console

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to construct 'Worker': Script at 'file:///C:/Users/XX/Desktop/AudioRecorder-master/js/recorderjs/recorderWorker.js' cannot be accessed from origin 'null'.
at new Recorder (file:///C:/Users/XX/Desktop/AudioRecorder-master/js/recorderjs/recorder.js:34:18)
at gotStream (file:///C:/Users/XX/Desktop/AudioRecorder-master/js/main.js:152:21)
```

is there other solution then recorder js to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This library looks a bit outdated, I would suggest using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDevices/getUserMedia API to perform what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: An example repository https://github.com/mdn/web-dictaphone and other helpful tips can be found here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaStream_Recording_API/Using_the_MediaStream_Recording_API

Answer (score 0):

```
Here's How u can make waves depending on your voice frequency
    
HTML: 
         <div class="app">
              <select name="" id="micSelect"></select>
            
              <select id="visSelect">
                <option value="frequencybars">Bar</option>
                <option value="sinewave">Wave</option>
                <option value="circle">Circle</option>
              </select>
            
              <a id="download" >Download</a>
            
              <div class="audio-controls">
                <button id="record">Record</button>
                <button id="stop">Stop</button>
                <audio id="audio" controls></audio>
              </div>
            
              <div id="msg">Recording...</div>
              <canvas width="500" height="300"></canvas>
            <div>
    
    CSS: 

        #msg {
          visibility: hidden;
          color: red;
          font-weight: bold;
          font-size: 22px;
          font-family: Verdana;
        }
        button {
          padding: 5px 10px;
          border: 1px solid grey;
          font-size: 18px;
          background: white;
        }
        
        .audio-controls {
          display: flex;
          align-items: center;
          padding-top: 20px;
          justify-content: center;
        }
        .audio-controls button {
          margin: 0px 5px;
        }
        canvas {
          margin-top: 10px;
          background-color: black;
        }
        select {
          height: 25px;
          margin: 0px 5px;
        }
        a {
          margin-left: 20px;
        }
        .app {
          text-align: center;
          padding-top: 20px;
        }
    
    JS: 
    
        (async () => {
          let leftchannel = [];
          let rightchannel = [];
          let recorder = null;
          let recording = false;
          let recordingLength = 0;
          let volume = null;
          let audioInput = null;
          let sampleRate = null;
          let AudioContext = window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext;
          let context = null;
          let analyser = null;
          let canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
          let canvasCtx = canvas.getContext("2d");
          let visualSelect = document.querySelector("#visSelect");
          let micSelect = document.querySelector("#micSelect");
          let stream = null;
          let tested = false;
        
          try {
            window.stream = stream = await getStream();
            console.log("Got stream");
          } catch (err) {
            alert("Issue getting mic", err);
          }
        
          const deviceInfos = await navigator.mediaDevices.enumerateDevices();
        
          var mics = [];
          for (let i = 0; i !== deviceInfos.length; ++i) {
            let deviceInfo = deviceInfos[i];
            if (deviceInfo.kind === "audioinput") {
              mics.push(deviceInfo);
              let label = deviceInfo.label || "Microphone " + mics.length;
              console.log("Mic ", label + " " + deviceInfo.deviceId);
              const option = document.createElement("option");
              option.value = deviceInfo.deviceId;
              option.text = label;
              micSelect.appendChild(option);
            }
          }
        
          function getStream(constraints) {
            if (!constraints) {
              constraints = { audio: true, video: false };
            }
            return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints);
          }
        
          setUpRecording();
        
          function setUpRecording() {
            context = new AudioContext();
            sampleRate = context.sampleRate;
        
            // creates a gain node
            volume = context.createGain();
        
            // creates an audio node from teh microphone incoming stream
            audioInput = context.createMediaStreamSource(stream);
        
            // Create analyser
            analyser = context.createAnalyser();
        
            // connect audio input to the analyser
            audioInput.connect(analyser);
        
            // connect analyser to the volume control
            // analyser.connect(volume);
        
            let bufferSize = 2048;
            let recorder = context.createScriptProcessor(bufferSize, 2, 2);
        
            // we connect the volume control to the processor
            // volume.connect(recorder);
        
            analyser.connect(recorder);
        
            // finally connect the processor to the output
            recorder.connect(context.destination);
        
            recorder.onaudioprocess = function (e) {
              // Check
              if (!recording) return;
              // Do something with the data, i.e Convert this to WAV
              console.log("recording");
              let left = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(0);
              let right = e.inputBuffer.getChannelData(1);
              if (!tested) {
                tested = true;
                // if this reduces to 0 we are not getting any sound
                if (!left.reduce((a, b) => a + b)) {
                  alert("There seems to be an issue with your Mic");
                  // clean up;
                  stop();
                  stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
                    track.stop();
                  });
                  context.close();
                }
              }
              // we clone the samples
              leftchannel.push(new Float32Array(left));
              rightchannel.push(new Float32Array(right));
              recordingLength += bufferSize;
            };
            visualize();
          }
        
          function mergeBuffers(channelBuffer, recordingLength) {
            let result = new Float32Array(recordingLength);
            let offset = 0;
            let lng = channelBuffer.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
              let buffer = channelBuffer[i];
              result.set(buffer, offset);
              offset += buffer.length;
            }
            return result;
          }
        
          function interleave(leftChannel, rightChannel) {
            let length = leftChannel.length + rightChannel.length;
            let result = new Float32Array(length);
        
            let inputIndex = 0;
        
            for (let index = 0; index < length; ) {
              result[index++] = leftChannel[inputIndex];
              result[index++] = rightChannel[inputIndex];
              inputIndex++;
            }
            return result;
          }
        
          function writeUTFBytes(view, offset, string) {
            let lng = string.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
              view.setUint8(offset + i, string.charCodeAt(i));
            }
          }
        
          function start() {
            recording = true;
            document.querySelector("#msg").style.visibility = "visible";
            // reset the buffers for the new recording
            leftchannel.length = rightchannel.length = 0;
            recordingLength = 0;
            console.log("context: ", !!context);
            if (!context) setUpRecording();
          }
        
          function stop() {
            console.log("Stop");
            recording = false;
            document.querySelector("#msg").style.visibility = "hidden";
        
            // we flat the left and right channels down
            let leftBuffer = mergeBuffers(leftchannel, recordingLength);
            let rightBuffer = mergeBuffers(rightchannel, recordingLength);
            // we interleave both channels together
            let interleaved = interleave(leftBuffer, rightBuffer);
        
            ///////////// WAV Encode /////////////////
            // from http://typedarray.org/from-microphone-to-wav-with-getusermedia-and-web-audio/
            //
        
            // we create our wav file
            let buffer = new ArrayBuffer(44 + interleaved.length * 2);
            let view = new DataView(buffer);
        
            // RIFF chunk descriptor
            writeUTFBytes(view, 0, "RIFF");
            view.setUint32(4, 44 + interleaved.length * 2, true);
            writeUTFBytes(view, 8, "WAVE");
            // FMT sub-chunk
            writeUTFBytes(view, 12, "fmt ");
            view.setUint32(16, 16, true);
            view.setUint16(20, 1, true);
            // stereo (2 channels)
            view.setUint16(22, 2, true);
            view.setUint32(24, sampleRate, true);
            view.setUint32(28, sampleRate * 4, true);
            view.setUint16(32, 4, true);
            view.setUint16(34, 16, true);
            // data sub-chunk
            writeUTFBytes(view, 36, "data");
            view.setUint32(40, interleaved.length * 2, true);
        
            // write the PCM samples
            let lng = interleaved.length;
            let index = 44;
            let volume = 1;
            for (let i = 0; i < lng; i++) {
              view.setInt16(index, interleaved[i] * (0x7fff * volume), true);
              index += 2;
            }
        
            // our final binary blob
            const blob = new Blob([view], { type: "audio/wav" });
        
            const audioUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            console.log("BLOB ", blob);
            console.log("URL ", audioUrl);
            document.querySelector("#audio").setAttribute("src", audioUrl);
            const link = document.querySelector("#download");
            link.setAttribute("href", audioUrl);
            link.download = "output.wav";
          }
        
          // Visualizer function from
          // https://webaudiodemos.appspot.com/AudioRecorder/index.html
          //
          function visualize() {
            WIDTH = canvas.width;
            HEIGHT = canvas.height;
            CENTERX = canvas.width / 2;
            CENTERY = canvas.height / 2;
        
            let visualSetting = visualSelect.value;
            console.log(visualSetting);
            if (!analyser) return;
        
            if (visualSetting === "sinewave") {
              analyser.fftSize = 2048;
              var bufferLength = analyser.fftSize;
              console.log(bufferLength);
              var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        
              canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
              var draw = function () {
                drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        
                analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);
        
                canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(200, 200, 200)";
                canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
                canvasCtx.lineWidth = 2;
                canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
        
                canvasCtx.beginPath();
        
                var sliceWidth = (WIDTH * 1.0) / bufferLength;
                var x = 0;
        
                for (var i = 0; i < bufferLength; i++) {
                  var v = dataArray[i] / 128.0;
                  var y = (v * HEIGHT) / 2;
        
                  if (i === 0) {
                    canvasCtx.moveTo(x, y);
                  } else {
                    canvasCtx.lineTo(x, y);
                  }
        
                  x += sliceWidth;
                }
        
                canvasCtx.lineTo(canvas.width, canvas.height / 2);
                canvasCtx.stroke();
              };
        
              draw();
            } else if (visualSetting == "frequencybars") {
              analyser.fftSize = 64;
              var bufferLengthAlt = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
              console.log(bufferLengthAlt);
              var dataArrayAlt = new Uint8Array(bufferLengthAlt);
        
              canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
              var drawAlt = function () {
                drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(drawAlt);
        
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArrayAlt);
        
                canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
                var barWidth = WIDTH / bufferLengthAlt;
                var barHeight;
                var x = 0;
        
                for (var i = 0; i < bufferLengthAlt; i++) {
                  barHeight = dataArrayAlt[i];
        
                  canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(" + (barHeight + 100) + ",50,50)";
                  canvasCtx.fillRect(
                    x,
                    HEIGHT - barHeight / 2,
                    barWidth,
                    barHeight / 2
                  );
        
                  x += barWidth + 1;
                }
              };
        
              drawAlt();
            } else if (visualSetting == "circle") {
              analyser.fftSize = 32;
              let bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
              console.log(bufferLength);
              let dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
        
              canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
              let draw = () => {
                drawVisual = requestAnimationFrame(draw);
        
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(dataArray);
                canvasCtx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                canvasCtx.fillRect(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
        
                // let radius = dataArray.reduce((a,b) => a + b) / bufferLength;
                let radius = dataArray[2] / 2;
                if (radius < 20) radius = 20;
                if (radius > 100) radius = 100;
                // console.log('Radius ', radius)
                canvasCtx.beginPath();
                canvasCtx.arc(CENTERX, CENTERY, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
                // canvasCtx.fillStyle = 'rgb(50,50,' + (radius+100) +')';
                // canvasCtx.fill();
                canvasCtx.lineWidth = 6;
                canvasCtx.strokeStyle = "rgb(50,50," + (radius + 100) + ")";
                canvasCtx.stroke();
              };
              draw();
            }
          }
        
          visualSelect.onchange = function () {
            window.cancelAnimationFrame(drawVisual);
            visualize();
          };
        
          micSelect.onchange = async (e) => {
            console.log("now use device ", micSelect.value);
            stream.getTracks().forEach(function (track) {
              track.stop();
            });
            context.close();
        
            stream = await getStream({
              audio: {
                deviceId: { exact: micSelect.value },
              },
              video: false,
            });
            setUpRecording();
          };
        
          function pause() {
            recording = false;
            context.suspend();
          }
        
          function resume() {
            recording = true;
            context.resume();
          }
        
          document.querySelector("#record").onclick = (e) => {
            console.log("Start recording");
            start();
          };
        
          document.querySelector("#stop").onclick = (e) => {
            stop();
          };
        })();
```

Live Demo: https://codepen.io/furki911/pen/jOYpvMx